# What methods are used to set attributes when data is pulled from a table in Ruby ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm using ActiveRecord 4.1.8 in a Ruby (not Rails) application. I have a table and a corresponding model that looks like the following:

```ruby
create_table 'people', :force => true do |t|
  t.string 'name'
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name=(name)
    puts "Attribute setter for name called with #{name}"
    write_attribute(:name, name)
  end
end
```

When I create a new instance of Person, I see the `Attribute setter for name called with...` written to STDOUT. However, when I reload the model instance, I do not see the message written to STDOUT.

```ruby
p = Person.create(name: 'foobar')
--> Attribute setter for name called with foobar

p.reload
--> <nothing>
```

The model is getting persisted to the database, so this makes me think `name=` isn't used when data is loaded into a model from the database. I need to modify certain data attributes when they're read in from the database, so does anyone know what other method I need to override?

Answer (score 0):

From the [`active_record/persistence.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb) source:

```
def reload(options = nil)
  clear_aggregation_cache
  clear_association_cache

  fresh_object =
    if options && options[:lock]
      self.class.unscoped { self.class.lock(options[:lock]).find(id) }
    else
      self.class.unscoped { self.class.find(id) }
    end

  @attributes = fresh_object.instance_variable_get('@attributes')
  @new_record = false
  self
end
```

It just replaces the attributes hash directly.  Seems like the easiest way to handle this is to override `reload` and patch things up after its called.

Comment: Thanks Nick. However, I guess I should be clear that my problem isn't necessarily just with the reload method, but with loading models from the database in general. For example, calling Person.all produces the same result (ie. name= not getting used).

Comment: It doesn't seem like AR is consistent enough in how it loads and modifies the attributes for there to be a single general solution if you're looking for one.